# Same Text Box in all Activities - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I outputted the temperature of a certain country in the first activity and I want to display itself in all activities. What should I do?

Comment: This question is a bit vague - what have you tried?  Perhaps share some code so others may better understand what you are getting at.  Better yet, have a look at [how to make a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There is no coding which I can show you in terms of this question. I have a text box which I filled up in the first activity and I want to keep showing it in all activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in sending activity write::

```
Intent intent = new Intent(current.this, Next.class);
intent.putExtra("keyName","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

in receiving activities write::

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyName");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try create singleton class

```
public class Temperature{

    private static Temperature INSTANCE = null;
    private int currentTemp;
    private Temperature(){}

    public static Temperature getInstance(){
        if(INSTANCE == null)
            INSTANCE = new Temperature();

        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void setTemperature(int temp){
        currentTemp = temp;
    }

    public int getTemperature(){
        return currentTemp;
    }

}



In activity 1:
    Temperature.getInstance().setTemperature(100)


In Activity 2
    String temp = String.valueOf(Temperature.getInstance().getTemperature());
    mTextView.setText(temp);
```